# The Tsiolkovsky equation derived via the Lagrange funtion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, rocket-science

I wanted to derive the [Tsiolkovsky rocket equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsiolkovsky_rocket_equation) using the Lagrange formalism.
$$ T = \frac{m(t)}{2}\dot{\xi(t)}^2 + \frac{\mu(t)}{2}(\dot{\xi(t)} - u)^2$$
$m$ - mass of the rocket

$\xi$ - some coordinate along which the rocket is moving

$\mu$ - mass of the thrown out fuel

$u$ - fuel velocity (in the rocket's reference frame).

[The standard procedure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_mechanics) yields the following equation of motion:
$$\ddot{\xi} (m+\mu) + \dot{\xi} (\dot{m} + \dot{\mu}) = \dot{\mu} u.$$
Since $m(t) = m_0 - \eta t$, and $\mu = \eta t$, there follow $\dot{m} + \dot{\mu} = 0$, $m+\mu = m_0$, and $\dot{\mu} = - \dot{m}$.

Therefore we have
$$m_0 \frac{d}{dt}\dot{\xi} = m_0 \ddot{\xi} = -u \eta.$$

This is not the anticipated result, the Tsiolkovsky equation is
$$\frac{d}{dt}\dot{\xi} = - u \frac{dm}{m},$$
where $m = m(t)$. Specifically, my issue is the fact that $m_0 \neq m(t)$.

Where is my mistake? Is the lagrangian wrong, or am I missing something else here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Lagrangian doesn't accurately describe the energy of the system.  You have a term in your kinetic energy
$$
\frac{\mu(t)}{2}(\dot{\xi(t)} - u)^2
$$
which is intended (I assume) to describe the kinetic energy $T_\text{fuel}(t)$ of all of the fuel that has been thrown out of the rocket up to time $t$.   But the fuel that's thrown out at a time $t_e < t$ will not be moving at speed $\dot{\xi}(t) - u$;  it will be moving at speed $\dot{\xi}(t_e) - u$.

We can try to write down an expression for $T_\text{fuel}(t)$ by integrating over the rocket's history.  The kinetic energy of the fuel that's thrown out between $t_e$ and $t_e + \Delta t_e$ will be
$$
\frac{\Delta \mu}{2}(\dot{\xi(t_e)} - u)^2 
$$
where $\Delta \mu \equiv \dot{\mu}(t_e) \Delta t_e$.   Thus, the total kinetic energy of the ejected fuel  will be
$$
T_\text{fuel}(t) = \frac{1}{2} \int_0^t \dot{\mu}(t_e) (\dot{\xi}(t_e) - u)^2 \, dt_e.
$$

Note that since your Lagrangian $\mathcal{L}$ will now involve an integral over the past history of the function $\xi(t)$, rather than simply depending on $\xi(t)$ and $\dot{\xi}(t)$.  This means that the plain-vanilla Euler-Lagrange equations $d/dt(\partial\mathcal{L}/\partial \dot{\xi}) = \partial\mathcal{L}/\xi$ cannot straightforwardly be applied.  You will instead have to return to first principles in the calculus of variations to derive the equations of motion.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. I think I understand what has to be done. Since I'm new to Stack Exchange, could you tell me whether I should or shouldn't update my question to also contain the corrected equation of motion?

Comment: @KubaKorsak:  No need to update your question.  If you want to exhibit the corrected equation of motion and show that it works, you can post that as an answer on your own question.  If, on the other hand, things still don't work, you can either edit the current question (if it's a minor change to this question) or post a new question (if it focuses on a different aspect of the problem.